# Java inheritance behaviour with instance of

Tags: java

I have the following

Class A extends B

B class is an abstract class
What will be returned if I do:

A a = new A();

a instance of B?

If it returns false, which solution I could use for having true as result?

Comment: This isn't really possible. Since B inherits from A, A is never an instance of B. It's the same reason why you can cast B as type A but you **can't** cast A as type B

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  Please tell us what you are actually trying to do, working against the language design like you are doing here is never going to turn out well.

Comment: @Rohlex32, it's the other way around, `A extends B`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Whoops! Misread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Define these classes. 

class A {} //It can be an abstract class as well.
class B extends A {}    

//Main code.
A b = new B();
System.out.println(b instanceof A); //prints true.
```

If you try B instanceof A // you will get a compilation error because B is not an object, but it is a class name.

Comment: And if class A is abstract ?

Comment: It will also work. You should run this code yourself in any IDE.

Comment: I don't think it matters @Capheda if A is abstract or not.  The answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

"x instanceof y" returns true if "object" x is instance of class "y". The word instance is used for an object. Since A and B are both classes the code should return a compilation error